# Composer Project - Redash + Redis + Postgres On Synology NAS

Tags: postgresql, docker, redis, yaml, synology

I am just diving into how Containers work, and have gotten pretty far, but when orchestrating a few images into one project yml file, I am running around in circles.

So I have the following images:

1. [redash/redash:latest](https://hub.docker.com/r/redash/redash) <-- The primary app...
2. [redis:latest](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/redis/)
3. [postgres:latest](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/postgres/)

I have all my ports open for each service, and tested that I could login to the postgres database from adminer:latest running in the same container.

I used a few different examples from the gitrepos, and other stack articles to build the bellow yml file and the help of @David Maze.

I believe now that I am missing a database setup file for Redash. The `scheduler` that interacts with my data base gives me:
`ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) relation “queries” does not exist`

I found this article: [discuss.redash.io](https://discuss.redash.io/t/docker-compose-installation-problem-psycopg2-programmingerror-query/427); where the poster is at the same point. A respondent said "Did you create the database tables?"

It looks that I need to run this command from from one of the Redash server consoles: `docker-compose run --rm server create_db` but I am using Synology's ContainerManager, not Docker...

Do I need a Volume to connect to the `server create_db` command?

Login is disabled on that site, otherwise I would try asking this question there.

Here is my updated yml:

```
version: "3.1"

x-redash-service: &redash-service
  image: redash/redash:latest
  depends_on:
    - db
    - cache
  restart: always

x-redash-env: &redash-env
  PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 0
  REDASH_LOG_LEVEL: "INFO"
  REDASH_REDIS_URL: "redis://cache:6379/0"
  REDASH_DATABASE_URL: "postgresql://postgres:postgresPassword@db/postgres"

services:
  redash:
    <<: *redash-service
    command: server
    ports:
      - "5003:5000"
    environment:
      <<: *redash-env
      REDASH_WEB_WORKERS: 4

  adhoc_worker:
    <<: *redash-service
    command: worker
    environment:
      <<: *redash-env
      QUEUES: "queries"
      WORKERS_COUNT: 2

  scheduler:
    <<: *redash-service
    command: scheduler
    environment:
      <<: *redash-env
      QUEUES: "celery"
      WORKERS_COUNT: 1

  scheduled_worker:
    <<: *redash-service
    command: worker
    environment:
      <<: *redash-env
      QUEUES: "scheduled_queries,schemas"
      WORKERS_COUNT: 1

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgresPassword
      POSTGRES_DB: postgresDatabase
    #command: "create_db"

  nginx:
    image: redash/nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "2501:80"
    depends_on:
      - redash
    restart: always

  cache:
    image: redis:latest
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./redis/data:/data:rw
```

Thanks again!

Please let me know if I should provide further details.

**EDIT_1:** `Update yml composition and status of build`

**EDIT_2:** `Update yml composition and status of build && Narrowed scope of issue.`

Answer (score 0):

There are two notable issues in the Compose file as you've shown it.

It's unclear where the IP address 192.168.x.x is from, but you don't need IP addresses to make connections between containers.  The Compose service names like `db` and `cache` are directly usable as host names.  Connections between containers don't use or consider `ports:` at all, so you need to use the standard port numbers for these services (and you could delete the other services' `ports:` if you don't need to connect to them from outside of Docker).

```yaml
environment:
  REDASH_REDIS_URL: redis://cache:6379/0
  REDASH_DATABASE_URL: postgresql://db:5432/0
```

The other problem is that your data stores are on a separate `redis_net`, but your application and workers aren't.  Compose creates a network named `default` and attaches containers to it.  Since the `redash` container is only on the `default` network and `db` is only on `redis_net`, they don't share a network and won't be able to talk to each other.

The easiest solution to this is just to delete *all* of the `networks:` blocks, everywhere in the file.  Everything will use the Compose-provided `default` network.

Both of these topics are discussed further in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.

Comment: thank you so much for your time. I made the updates you suggested and continued to research Composer documents. I am not sure if I am any closer though. Can you review the edits I made to the question above?